# GUI to create and fill database with data and export it to sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

So, I have a relatively common task, and hope to get some suggestions here.

Idea is that I have a small database in mind, database will have at least 2 types of tables:

1. dictionary-table - it will have just the id and few columns of text
2. aggregation-table - it should combine different dictionary entries into some aggregation, so it will be basically mapping id's of different dictionary entries all together.

So, what I hoped to do is to have some software that will help me to fill database easily. I will add data to dictionary-tables, and will say that 'this particular column of my aggregation table can have values only from this dictionary-table', so I would type words, and it will just add id's from dictionary-table instead. You know, like a relationships in database.

Except that in the end I want it to be a plain sqlite database, and sqlite doesn't support relationships.

So what I want is some cool high-level GUI tool that will simplify the way I input data to database, and will help me to maintain the data when DB grows in future, but also be able to export to a simple SQLite.

I tried: SQliteBrowser, SqliteAdmin, Libreoffice Base + Sqlite ODBC. Neither supports what I want.

Anything else worth checking out?

Comment: I would write the form by PHP on some local or intranet server..

Comment: Yes, looks like that will the only way to approach and solve this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand, but shouldn't you just normalize your data instead? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: It's not about normalization, it's about having a comfortable way of managing your data.
Imagine you are making a cook book with 10.000 recipes. How would you manage your database of recipes?

Answer (score 1):

you said

> ...be a plain sqlite database, and sqlite doesn't support relationships.

But sqlite supports relationships. By default it is disabled. you can enable it with

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

now you can code your requirement by having proper foreign key.

you said

> I will add data to dictionary-tables,

Instead of multiple dictionary tables, just have one dictionary table and add one more column in it as dictionary_name

your aggregate table can simply have foreign key referring the dictionary table

Comment: 'dictionary-table' is a syntax abstraction. To go into details - it's a table with multiple columns some of which are specific for the language. But thanks, I will consider your idea.
About the whole idea - what I want is a neat and simple way to fill the database and maintain/add new data later when I want it. Manually - I have all dictionary and aggregate tables working, aggregates having id's that point to dictionary entries. And it's fine while there isn't much data. But there will be thousands of entires, and building aggregate-table manually adding all IDs will be big PITA.

Answer (score 1):

How about PhpLiteAdmin? - https://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/

It allows you to directly add/modify the structure and data of an sqlite database but also allows import and export of tables, structure, indexes, and data (SQL, CSV). If you're dealing with thousands of entries then this may be the important feature for whatever tool you use.

There's no installation and it's open-source

Comment: This will probably be almost the same as sqlite browser, just allowing to browse entries and fill tables, but with no additional features. For example, I would like to say that this particular cell can have only id's of that particular table, but when I type something manually that cell should auto-suggest not yet added entries grabbing text from 'text' cell of that other table. See what I mean? I will type text, or select it from dropdown, but software will add only id's